# Get Office 365 API access token without user interaction

Tags: c#, office365, office365api

I want to add a feature to my application so that it will be able to add calendar events to outlook.com without user interaction.

All the examples I've seen require user to login to be able to access office 365 api token. How do i get that token without user interaction?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Client Credential** to request the token instead of **OAuth 2.0 Code Grant flow**.

Here is the request for your reference:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<clientId>
&client_secret=<clientSecret>
&resource=https://outlook.office.com
```

And here is the sample using the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` to request hte token:

```
   public static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, string secrect)
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourTenantName}";
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secrect);
        AuthenticationResult authResult=await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

More detail about Office 365 REST, please refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api#supported-versions-of-api).

Comment: If I understand correctly I need to pay to get tenantId?

Comment: Yes. You can login the classic Azure portal and you can get the tenantId from the URL of browser like this https://manage.windowsazure.com/rekenoutlook.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/ActiveDirectoryExtension/Directory/{tenantId}/directoryQuickStart.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Hi, can I use this access token to read the email from my office 365 account?

Comment: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory is marked obsolete now. This solution is out of date.