# Microsoft Stream SSO with Azure AD programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I know that is possible to configure the Azure AD SSO between Office 365 portals, but how can I do it programmatically?

Are there any ways in local ASP.NET web application to authenticate a user in Azure AD programmatically using username/password without prompt Azure AD logon screen, get a token and then redirect to Microsoft Stream page with the user authenticated?

I cannot find this functionality in Microsoft Graph API and the Microsoft Stream API are in development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this (resource owner password credential) flow to log in with specific user/pass https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc however, this will get you a token for azure ad app, I don't think it will work on the office 365 portals / stream portal though you can try it. It's mainly for accessing apis and aad applications. but feel free to give it a try, its the only way to authenticate with user/pass without interaction that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROPC Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get the token  which helps in authenticate to **Microsoft Stream** without login popup.

Here is the request for your reference:

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

> **Note:** Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most
>   scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended.
>   This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and
>   carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only
>   use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Based on the above note it advises using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). Please refer similar question with [client credential flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646611/get-office-365-api-access-token-without-user-interaction) that may help you