# How are organization internal web apps working without user manual login on Windows-based machines?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Could someone help me, how can I get Login User Profile Information/accessToken without manual Interaction with User

Comment: Because authentication is not enabled maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [ROPC Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get the token  which helps in authenticate to  without manual Interaction with User.

Here is the request for your reference:

```
POST {tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access
&username=MyUsername@myTenant.com
&password=SuperS3cret
&grant_type=password
```

> **Note:** Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most
> scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended.
> This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and
> carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only
> use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Based on the above note it advises using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). Please refer similar question with [client credential flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646611/get-office-365-api-access-token-without-user-interaction) that may help you.If you use client credential flow then user login itself is not required.

Comment: Why suggest a non-recommend flow like ROPC for a question that's not even clear?